# How to access a document cookie through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I created a cookie with `document.cookie` and when I do an alert it returns

```
nav=Panel; cookieValue=Panel; test=1; nav=Panel; cookieValue=buyer;
```

How can I access the last, `cookieValue`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have created a cookie using,
    document.cookie = "I am a cookie!";
To read the cookie and store it in a variable, you can use,
     var x = document.cookie;

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way but you *could* convert to an array:

```
var cookie = "nav=Panel; cookieValue=Panel; test=1; nav=Panel; cookieValue=buyer; ";

var cookieArray = cookie.split('; ');

alert(cookieArray[cookieArray.length-2]);
```

Comment: Note, a value, per specification, might contain URI encoded values.

Answer (score 0):

This answer gives three solutions.

### Step by step solution

The `key=value` pairs are split into an array, then the pair is split at `=` to get the name. The function makes use of ECMA Script 5's [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). The resulting object `memo` is returned if it is no longer `null`. In this case `reduce()` is gracefully used as *`find()` that returns an altered value*.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    return document.cookie.split("; ").reduce(function(memo, token){
        var pair;
        if (memo) {
            // we've already a value, don't bother parsing further values
            return memo;
        }
        pair = token.split("=");
        if (pair[0] === name) {
            // return the decoded value as memoized value if the key matches
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }, null);
}
```

### Step by step with the option to get all cookies

The `key=value` pairs are split into an array, then the pair is split at `=` to get the name. The function makes use of ECMA Script 5's `reduce()` to transform the intermediate array into an object where `key` will be an attribute of that object.

```
function getCookies() {
    return document.cookie.split("; ").reduce(function(cookies, token){
        // split key=value into array
        var pair = token.split("=");
        // assign value (1) as object's key with (0)
        cookies[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        // pass through the key-value store
        return cookies;
    }, { /* start with empty "cookies" object */ });
}

function getCookie(name) {
    return getCookies()[name];
}
```

### Quick and dirty

Uses a dynamically created Regular Expression to extract the `key=value` pair's value, finally decodes the value.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent(
        document.cookie.replace(
            new RegExp("^.*" + name + "=([^\\s;]+).*$"), "$1"));
}
```